# How to represent already built API classes on uml diagrams?

Tags: uml

When part of my solution is to use already built classes (for instance,Java's API classes) to promote reuse's principle, how do i represent these in uml diagrams like class, sequence and activity diagrams? Is it more common to represent them on diagrams or to ommit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have different options. But usually I create component elements representing libs (and APIs). Those components can either hold the classes they implement directly or you can associate them (e.g. via a `<<realize>>` relation). It's a good idea to attach lollipops and sockets to the component to show the implemented and required interfaces. The latter can also be used in sequence diagrams.

Comment: Assuming I use a java object method to perform some task at a given step of my program. Do i have to specify in sequence diagrams or activity diagram all the relations and operations that this object has to other java objects?

Comment: No. Each behavior diagram focuses on a certain aspect. It's to be seen as part of a collaboration (which represents the realization of a use case). And you don't even need to light all aspects if they are obvious. Just try shedding as much light as necessary to make a clear picture the reader of the model can understand. Better few than nothing. And too much is contra-productive too.